# Setting nano cursor using mouse via putty doesn't work if sudo

Tags: sudo, nano

I needed to be able to set the cursor using mouse when editing text via `nano` over `putty`. I have already set the below in `~/.nanorc`:

```
set mouse
```

If I start `nano file` just like that then it works, but if I require elevated rights and `sudo nano file` then it's not. How on earth is that possible? I suppose in that case `nano` is using another `.nanorc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suppose in that case nano is using another .nanorc?

Yep. When you run `sudo nano file`, `HOME` environment variable is set to `/root`, so `nano` looks for `.nanorc` there.

Just add the setting into `/root/.nanorc`, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One more Q here if I may. Since I set up the above I can't paste anything into nano. I used to use right-click to do so.

Comment: Never mind. Shift+Insert is still working.